# Media Library not showing images but still acknowledges existence

Tags: media, media-library

I have no idea why this is happening. I've read A LOT about it and there don't seem to be any solutions. I once read that it was expected behaviour because of some plug-ins and that the Hotfix plugin would fix it but that wasn't the case.

[image: media library]

However, if I go to the actual media gallery through the sidebar, I can see all my images. I've tried searching and filtering the page in the image but still no images show.

**Any one familiar with this problem and know of a fix?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little known error caused by creating a custom taxonomy called 'type'. To solve just need to change the taxonomy's name.

Comment: How do one do that?

Comment: I googled how to do that, but when checking the database there is no taxonomy called "type".